# killing a running thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How to kill a running thread in java

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94011/how-to-abort-a-thread-in-a-fast-and-clean-way-in-java

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can ask the thread to interrupt, by calling [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

Note that a few other methods with similar semantics exist - `stop()` and `destroy()` - but they are *deprecated*, because they are [unsafe](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Don't be tempted to use them.

Comment: . destroy() is not depricated.

Comment: See Bozho's "unsafe" link, in particular the "What should I use instead of Thread.stop()" section, to see the canonical way to actuall *kill* a thread.  Interrupt will merely cause any currently-executing blocking calls to stop running, but will not in itself stop the thread from executing.

Comment: @JavaUser it is, as of Java 1.5

Comment: @JavaUser - there is also the "slight problem" that the javadoc prior to JDK 1.5 for `destroy()` says *"(This method is not implemented.)"*.  It won't work even if you try to use it.

Answer (score 6):

As Bozho said, Thread.interrupt() is the generic and right way to do it. But remember that it requires the thread to cooperate; It is very easy to implement a thread that ignores interruption requests.

In order for a piece of code to be interruptible this way, it shouldn't ignore any InterruptedException, and it should check the interruption flag on each loop iteration (using Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()). Also, it shouldn't have any non-interruptible blocking operations. If such operations exist (e.g. waiting on a socket), then you'll need a more specific interruption implementation (e.g. closing the socket).

Answer (score 2):

Shortly you need [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

For more details check the section `How do I stop a thread that waits for long periods (e.g., for input)` in this article [Why Are `Thread.stop`, `Thread.suspend`,`Thread.resume` and `Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit` Deprecated?](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).