# How to stop a running thread when Activity on destroy at Android?

Tags: android

I used some thread objects in my Android activity.  But these threads do not stop itself  when Activity on destroy. My code for thread-stopping as following:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

Above code is not only working for thread object stopping but also throws an InterruptedException. What's the correct way to stop a running thread without exceptions?

---

is it not an error when thread object throws InterruptedException?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699292/how-to-stop-all-worker-threads-in-android-application

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

```
volatile boolean stop = false;

public void run() {
    while ( !stop ) {
     log.v("Thread", "Thread running..." );
      try {
      Thread.sleep( 1000 );
      } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
      log.v("Thread","Thread interrupted..." );
      }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stop = true;
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    thread.interrupt();
    super.onDestroy();   
}
```

Comment: So, is not an error when thread object throws InterruptedException?

Answer (score 0):

trying to stop the thread from outside is not reliable.

I suggest to use global param  using SharePreferences or Application Context, ( e.g. IS_APP_ACTIVE ) across your app
 and let thread kill itself.

let me try to explain a bit...

in your Activity

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

// isAppActive
        CommonUtils.setAppActive(mContext, true);
}

protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

// isAppActive
        CommonUtils.setAppActive(mContext, true);
}
```

in your thread

```
if ( !CommonUtils.isAppActive(mContext) )
```

just get out of the thread loop.

Answer (score 0):

I perform this way.
In your activity

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

in your Thread

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // stop your thread
    if (interrupted()) {
        return;
    }
    // do your work
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Adding `finish();` should end the Activity when onDestroy() or anything else (eg. a button is pressed) is called. When you use onDestroy(), make sure `super.onDestroy();` is put after everything else is called.

Comment: Hi, it's keep throwing InterruptedException after I added the finish()  function call.  Should I override something method into my Runnable class??  By the way, I have no click -1 button to your post