# How to start coroutines to run indefinitely and stop during onPause of activity life cycle

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to using **`co routines`** .... I am trying something like [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544515/how-to-stop-a-running-thread-when-activity-on-destroy-at-android)

- Start a thread(using co routines) on `resume()` of activity
- Run the thread indifinately
- Set textview every `5 seconds`
- Stop `onPause()` of activity life cycle

Comment: visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsHTxOILP5g .very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
private var job: Job? = null

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    job = lifecycleScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            /* do work */
            delay(5000L)
        }
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = null
    super.onStop()
}
```

Comment: `lifecycleScope` comes from the [androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0+](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) dependency. A nice addition so you don't have to manage your own scope. Thanks for that! Though in this case the job is cancelled anyway before the scope would but still