# How to handle socket events as background service in Android?

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm new to Android development and I wanted my app to be able to detect socket events even when app is not active via Background service (so I can do push notification e.g if there's a new message triggered by a socket event like how Whatsapp and others do it).

I implemented Background service and an application class that starts the service but stuck where and how to put the socket events as Runnable task in my Background service.

I modified the socket.io android chat project example below and added service and application class.

**ChatApplication.java**

```
package com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ChatApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    // called when the application is starting, before any other application objects have been created
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // represents our background service
        Intent background = new Intent(this, SocketBackgroundService.class);
        startService(background);
    }

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

**SocketBackgroundService.java**

```
package com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class SocketBackgroundService extends Service {
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Thread backgroundThread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something in here
            Log.i("INFO", "SOCKET BACKGROUND SERVICE IS RUNNING");

            //TODO - how to handle socket events here?
            //How do I do something like mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect); here?
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if( !this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need the socket to be alive even after your application is stopped. Move your socket to the Background service and then you can add the socket events in the service.

Comment: The syntax for that is the one I'm actually trying to figure out, how to move the Socket from Application to the Runnable function in the Background service. :)

Comment: Move this private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

Comment: to SocketBackgroundService.

Comment: and add mSocket.on("event",Callback) to listen to your events.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion but have problem accessing mSocket in my activities to do something like `mSocket.emit`. How will this be done if mSocket is now on service class?

Comment: For that you can implement IBinder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html and return in the object in this. @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it worked :) How do I callback an activity method in Service. I want all of my events (mSocket.on, mSocket.off) to reside in the Service instead of spread across Activities. What's more appropriate to use... Interface or LocalBroadcastManager?

Answer (score 6):

You open socket on main thread. Do not open socket connections on main thread, it will gives you ANR(application not responding) error which is occur due to lots of heavy work on UI thread. It blocks UI thread for more than 5 sec. So I suggest you to open socket connections on thread inside service.
Here is example using plain socket:

1. Create one service class for starting thread on background service
2. Create on Thread class for opening socket connection on thread
3. create separate class for socket communication

   ```
   public class SocketBackgroundService extends Service {

   private SocketThread mSocketThread;

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

       mSocketThread = SocketThread.getInstance();
   }


   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       //stop thread and socket connection here
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       if (mSocketThread.startThread) {
       } else {
           stopSelf();
       }

       return START_STICKY;
   }
   }

   public class SocketThread extends Thread {

   private static SocketThread mSocketThread;
   private SocketClient mSocketClient;

   private SocketThread() {
   }

   // create single instance of socket thread class
   public static SocketThread getInstance() {
       if (mSocketThread == null)//you can use synchronized also
       {
           mSocketThread = new SocketThread();
       }
       return mSocketThread;
   }


   public boolean startThread() {
         mSocketClient = new SocketClient();
       if (socketClient.isConnected()) {
           mSocketThread.start()
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       super.run();
       while (mSocketClient.isConnected()) {
           // continue listen
       }
       // otherwise remove socketClient instance and stop thread
   }

   public class SocketClient {
       //write all code here regarding opening, closing sockets
       //create constructor
       public SocketClient() {
           // open socket connection here
       }

       public boolean isConnected() {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: hello Sam, I'm new to android development and would like to know on which part did you detect my code is running on main thread? I got the background service running and able to listen to sockets through the advice of Ashish above. I'd like to improve it as you mentioned this issue. Here is my working code: https://gist.github.com/arvi/a31843d26dcd1fd69c32bbe2bb7130d7 If you can spare time to advice, thank you so much, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Hi Woppi, This code looks fine to me. You really do well code and improved very well. Do you have any facing any problem regarding this code?

Comment: Hello @Sam, I really appreciate you taking time to review my code. It means a lot to me. So now I'm clear that I've handled the threads well. I've also shared the gist in slack community just today to get some feedback (I'm arviio) https://androidchat.slack.com/messages/beginners/, and it was recommended that I should use broadcast receivers instead of bound service. With this, I can get rid of AppSocketEvents and ServiceConn in my activity classes... and just use service for everything. I've yet also to look at EventBus. My problem is my confidence if I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: Hi Woppi, Regarding choosing correct method/ way I will give an example or suggestion, For achieving our destination their are lots of way, But we have to choose correct one or at least we have to try it. Just like in technical things, We have to do first R&D on project then we get lots of ways to perform project. Then we choose appropriate one. If it fails then we choose next one. So do not bother about that. If you fail...you will learn more.

Comment: Code has some issues near startThread. //public boolean startThread() { = new SocketClient();// code has no initialize prop. Also the startThread methods should be static. Maybe the person edit this, did mistake.

Comment: Thanks for telling about opening a socket in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashish and @Mangesh Sambare both show/state you should have the Web Socket part of the background service, however there are some things you should know before doing such.

- In reference to the Socket.IO documentation

> CAUTION!
> Socket.IO is not meant to be used in a background service for mobile applications.
> The Socket.IO library keeps an open TCP connection to the server, which may result in a high battery drain for your users. Please use a dedicated messaging platform like [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for this use case.

If you still insist on not following the suggestion then consider using plain web sockets (again in the background service). This will give you better control over how the socket is kept open, and will still cause battery drain, but should be less than that of Socket.io.