# How to stop thread safely in android?

Tags: java, android

how can I stop threads safely?

```
 downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {

  });
  downloadThread.start();
 }
```

Comment: This is a frequent question with frequent good answers like this: [How to abort a thread in a fast and clean way in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94011/how-to-abort-a-thread-in-a-fast-and-clean-way-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using normal thread to do background jobs if u will use Android sdk's [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), there you can find a `cancel()`.

Comment: This isn't answering the question.

Comment: AsyncTask was deprecated in API level 30.

Answer (score 3):

Interrupt the thread. In the `run()` method of the thread, check the value of `isInterrupted()` at the end of different logical blocks.

For instance, say your `run()` method can be broken up into three logical steps
 - creating a network connection, downloading an image and saving the image to a file. At the end of each of these steps, check for `isCancelled()` and stop the operation discarding all state at that point.

```
class NetworkFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    public void doInBackground(String... params){
       String url = params[0];

       //Open connection if not cancelled
       if(isCancelled()){
           conn.close();
           return;
       }
       NetworkConnection conn = new NetworkConnection();


       //Download the image if not cancelled
       if(isCancelled()){
           conn.close();
           result.discard();
           return;
       }
       NetworkResult result = conn.fetchUrl(url);
       conn.close();

       //Save the image to a file if not cancelled
       if(isCancelled()){
          result.discard();
          return;
       }
       File file = new File();
       file.dump(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wohoo! Old question! Never realized

Comment: Can you give some example, how to do what you propose?

Comment: There you go. And please note the change from isInterrupted() to isCancelled(). isInterrupted() is a method on a Thread, not an AsyncTask. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one seem to be setting isRunning to false.

Comment: I need general solution , not for this .

Comment: Similar solutions is one way I've employed multiple times. while(do_run()) { do stuff }