# android voice command do httppost

Tags: java, android

I got this example of voice recognition. I added some code for a httppost command. I want, when i say the word DOG to make a httppost. All works fine, but when i say the word DOG and when it's supposed to do my httppost i get these errors:

```
05-25 21:31:24.889: D/AndroidRuntime(15191): Shutting down VM
05-25 21:31:24.889: W/dalvikvm(15191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aab300)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample/com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample.VoiceRecognitionActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3267)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3310)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:142)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample.VoiceRecognitionActivity.cici(VoiceRecognitionActivity.java:157)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample.VoiceRecognitionActivity.onActivityResult(VoiceRecognitionActivity.java:113)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3263)
05-25 21:31:24.909: E/AndroidRuntime(15191):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private EditText metTextHint;
    private ListView mlvTextMatches;
    private Spinner msTextMatches;
    private Button mbtSpeak;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognition);
        metTextHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTextHint);
        mlvTextMatches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTextMatches);
        msTextMatches = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sNoOfMatches);
        mbtSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSpeak);
    }

    public void checkVoiceRecognition() {
        // Check if voice recognition is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() == 0) {
            mbtSpeak.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Voice recognizer not present",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void speak(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        // Specify the calling package to identify your application
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass()
                .getPackage().getName());

        // Display an hint to the user about what he should say.
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, metTextHint.getText()
                .toString());

        // Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);

        // If number of Matches is not selected then return show toast message
        if (msTextMatches.getSelectedItemPosition() == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select No. of Matches from spinner",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        int noOfMatches = Integer.parseInt(msTextMatches.getSelectedItem()
                .toString());
        // Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be
        // sorted where the first result is the one with higher confidence.

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, noOfMatches);

        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)

            //If Voice recognition is successful then it returns RESULT_OK
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                ArrayList<String> textMatchList = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if (!textMatchList.isEmpty()) {
                    // If first Match contains the 'search' word
                    // Then start web search.
                    if (textMatchList.get(0).contains("search")) {

                        String searchQuery = textMatchList.get(0).replace("search",
                        " ");
                        Intent search = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                        search.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchQuery);
                        startActivity(search);
                    } else if (textMatchList.get(0).contains("dog")) {
                        postTo();
                } else {
                        // populate the Matches
                        mlvTextMatches
                        .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                textMatchList));
                    }

                }
            //Result code for various error.    
            }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR){
                showToastMessage("Audio Error");
            }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_CLIENT_ERROR){
                showToastMessage("Client Error");
            }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NETWORK_ERROR){
                showToastMessage("Network Error");
            }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH){
                showToastMessage("No Match");
            }else if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_SERVER_ERROR){
                showToastMessage("Server Error");
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    void showToastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }





    public void postTo()
    {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/script.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "cracanel"));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its a NetworkOnMainThread exception. You cannot run network related operation on the main ui thread. You should use asynctask for this purpose.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

For asynctask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can also create your own thread and execute httppost. But make sure you don't update ui on the backgroudn thread. Asyntask makes it easier for you

Example:

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
                    // invoked on the ui thread.
                    // display progress dialog     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                     //invoked on the ui thread
                     // dismiss progress dialog  
                     // result of doinbackground computation is a parameter to this
                     // can update ui here
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //invoked on the background thread
                    // do not update ui
                    // execute http post here  
                    postTo(); // call your post method here 
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
        new TheTask().execute(); // load on ui thread
```

Can pass parameter to the constructor of asynctask. You can also pass parameter to doinbackground directly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do your network connections on  a separate thread or with an AsyncTask.

You can see how I did this in this code here (AsyncTask + callback): https://github.com/nedwidek/Android-Rest-API

Or use search to find many other examples. Such as:
 - [android wait asynctask to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997547/android-wait-asynctask-to-finish)
 - [Using wait in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122812/using-wait-in-asynctask)

AsyncTask is intended for short duration background tasks (such as network access).

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple external thread, use the Asynctask if you need to update your UI during the process 
Try this in your code:

```
else if (textMatchList.get(0).contains("dog")) {
           Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   postTo();
                }
           });
           backgroundThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do networking on UI thread. Use AsyncTask.