# Async task wont stop

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

```
package com.example.asynctask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

        private boolean flag = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressbar.setMax(100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            //progressbar.setMax(0);
            flag = false;
            Log.v("onCancelled:flag", String.valueOf(flag));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int start = params[0];
            for (int i = start; i <= 100; i=i+10) {

                if (!flag) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    publishProgress(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("ThreadError", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progressbar.setProgress(values[0]); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.v("Progress", "Finish");
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ProgressTask task = new ProgressTask();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:
            task.execute(10);
            break;

        case R.id.stop:
            task.cancel(true);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is a symple AsyncTask app which starts to update the progress bar when you hit Start. But when you will hit stop, it wont stop. Thing is when you call ***task.cancel(true)***, ***onCancelled()*** methods does gets invoked and changes the value of flag to **false** but in ***onCancelled()*** value of flag remains true. I have also tried ***isCancelled()*** in place of flag varaible with no success. For a moment my problem is similar to [Ollie C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959628/android-asynctask-wont-stop-when-cancelled-why), but no exceptions are thrown in my case.

Comment: In this line `ProgressTask task = new ProgressTask();`. Your `task` is in the scope of that method. You should create an class instance `task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wenhui pointed out in the comment, I made a silly mistake in which I declared and instantiated task inside ***onClick(View v)***.