# AsyncTask is not being cancelled on Android 4+ (works on 2.3)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm having the same situation as here: [Android AsyncTask won't stop when cancelled, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959628/android-asynctask-wont-stop-when-cancelled-why)

I set a timer to kill the AsyncTask after a couple of seconds.
It works perfectly on android 2.3.5 (the task is cancelled after the timeout I set), but for some reason it doesn't work on Android 4+)

This is the relevant code (all inside the AsyncTask class)

```
private class TaskKiller extends TimerTask {
    private AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> mTask;
    public TaskKiller(AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> task) {
        mTask = task;
    }
    public void run() {
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
    // Setting the Task timeout.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TaskKiller(this), 3000);

    response = HttpRequest(url); // this method makes an HttpPost request.
    // This, I think, is where android 4+ is unable to cancel the task (while making the http request). It is perfectly cancelled in 2.3.5, though.
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    Log.e("TASK CANCELED","...");
}
```

It's working like a charm in android 2.3.

**Do you have any clue on How to make it work in android 4+?**

Comment: try to put break after cancel asynctask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538714/stop-asynctask-doinbackground-method/16538887. check this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private HttpUriRequest mRequest;


protected String doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
    ...
    mRequest = new HttpGet(url); // or HttpPost
    response = client.execute(mRequest);
    ...
}

private void myCancelationRoutine() {
      mRequest.cancel();
      mTask.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Good idea. I didn't think of if. Unfortunately, eclipse is showing an error and requests me to "Add Cast" to mRequest (it adds a Timer cast!). So it doesn't work, so far. I'll test similar approaches and get back.

Comment: The solution was simple. Instead of "mRequest.cancel()" I had to use mRequest.abort(), and it worked. Thanks for this simple and bright solution.