# Each thread should run for 10 minutes and then interrupt the thread if the time is over

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to make an `ExecutorService` implementation that can be provided with a timeout or interrupt for each thread.

In my below example, suppose I am spawning `2 threads` (in actual scenario, this number will be high), then I need to make sure `each thread` should be running for `10 minutes`.
That means, `Thread1 will run for 10 minutes` and `Thread2 will run for 10 minutes as well`. If 10 minutes is over then I need to interrup the thread or timeout.

Below is the code I have so far and I am not able to understand how should I add this `interrupt or timeout` functionality here in such a clean way so that if I am making this `no of threads` parameter configurable in my code then it should work properly there as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;
    final long exp_time_millis = 600000; //10 minutes

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);


    for (int i = 0, i< noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask());
    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Thread running...");
            try {

        /* make a select sql to the database 
         * and measure how much time it is taking in 
         * returning the response
         */

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

I have already seen few articles on the SO but I was not able to find anything which matches my scenario and I can implement that easily.

**Updated Code:-**

I am trying the below code but it gives me error on the catch block in the run method. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
public class ThreadTimeout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int noOfThreads = 2;

        //create thread pool with given size 
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(noOfThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i< noOfThreads; i++) {
            final Future future = service.submit(new ThreadTask());
            scheduleService.schedule(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    future.cancel(true);
                }
            }, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

           //make a database connection

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Thread running...");
            try {
                /*
                 * make a select sql to the database and measure
                 * how much time it is taking in returning the
                 * response
                 */
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a second `ScheduledExecutorService`.  You can submit the `Future` returned from your original submissions to the `ScheduledExecutorService` to cancel.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(n);
for (int i = 0, i< noOfThreads; i++) { 
   final Future future = service.submit(new ThreadTask());
   scheduleService.schedule(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           future.cancel(true);
       }
  }, 10, TimeUnits.MINUTES);
}
```

Now the `ThreadTask` needs to respond to interruption or else this will not help.

Comment: Thanks John for the help. I have updated my question with the snippet from your code and my code. But I am getting error in the catch block asking me to remove the exception. But I think you mentioned to me that `ThreadTask` needs to respond to `interruption`. Right? I know, I can add `Thread.sleep` but in actual code, I will be doing `select sql calls` to the database. Do you know how can I do that? Or if you can provide me the full flow by combining your code and mine code, that will be of great help to me as well. By that I can understand better.

Comment: And one more thing ,`newScheduledThreadPool(n)` here n should be same as number of threads for `newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);` right?

Comment: Hi John, can you please help me here with my questions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `And one more thing ,newScheduledThreadPool(n)` not necessarily.  You can get away with 1 or a couple threads.  All they will do is signal to the other threads they should cancel.  That thread usually wouldn't be doing much work.

Comment: `Do you know how can I do that?` depends on if the SQL driver itself is responsive to interruption.  You can also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492777/stopping-a-non-looping-java-thread.  You can instead have `if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` as a condition.

Comment: If you can't do the latter suggestion and your driver is responsive to interruption via `Statement.cancel` there is a sort of hack you can do to achieve interruption with `Future.cancel`

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to use the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...);` method and then the `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` method.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++) {
    service.submit(new ThreadTask());
}
// we always need to shutdown the service _after_ we've submitted all jobs
service.shutdown();
// now we wait for those tasks to finish for 10 minutes
if (!service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    // if we timed out waiting for the tasks to finish, forcefully interrupt them
    service.shutdownNow();
}
```

Note that this will interrupt the threads but that will only cause certain methods such as `Thread.sleep()`, `Object.wait()`, and some others to throw `InterruptedException`.  It also sets the interrupt bit on the thread which can be tested with `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.  It will *not* "kill" the thread like you would a unix process.