# Delete threaded Toast message

Tags: android, multithreading, toast

I'm trying to "remove" a `Toast` when switching from a tab to another one, so assuming pausing the focused tab activity. Basically I could apply the cancel method to a single `Toast` object, or assign it to null. This works.

The point is when I use TextView and thread the Toast, then the Toast is still visible even if I stop the thread. I started from [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8707203/461212) to thread the Toast and trying to stop it according to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/95636/461212).

How to stop the thread and remove the toast from the system queue, or is there any better solution to achieve that goal (eg multiple toasts in a single activity, stopping showing toasts when swapping from an activity to another one)  ?

---

Calling a Toast (this is Ok):

```
private void showSingleToast(String toastText, int color, long duration_ms) {


    if (mySingleToast instanceof Toast) {
        mySingleToast.setText(toastText);

        if (null != toastView)
            if (toastView instanceof TextView)
                toastView.setTextColor(color);

        ToastExpander.showFor(mySingleToast, duration_ms);
    }
}
```

---

Threading the Toast.show()

```
public class ToastExpander extends Thread {

    public static final String TAG = "ToastExpander";

    static Thread t;// = null;

    // Must be volatile:
    static volatile boolean stopFlag = false;
    static long scan_freq = 300;

    public static void showFor(final Toast aToast, final long durationInMilliseconds) {

        aToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        t = new Thread() {
            long timeElapsed = 0l;

            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (timeElapsed <= durationInMilliseconds || !stopFlag) {
                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        aToast.show();
                        sleep(scan_freq);
                        timeElapsed += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                    }

                    // doesn't work: aToast.cancel();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            } /* end of "run" */

        }; /* end of Thread */

        t.start();



    } /* end showFor */

    public static void cancel() {
    stopFlag = true;
    }
}
```

---

Trying to "remove" the Toast (does not work)

```
private void hideSingleToast() {
    //hideTextView(toastView);
    toastView = null;
    ToastExpander.cancel();
    mySingleToast.cancel();
    //mySingleToast= null;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution for me.

```
public static void show(final Toast aToast, final String usr_msg, final long durationInMilliseconds,
            final TextView myView, final int myColor) {

    // Instanciate Toast
    aToast.setText(usr_msg);
    aToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    // Instanciate TV
    myView.setTextColor(myColor);

    t = new Thread() {
        long timeElapsed = 0l;

        public void run() {

            try {

                // Make sure view exists

                // Show Toast in the view
                while (!stopFlag) {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    aToast.show();
                    sleep(scan_freq);
                    timeElapsed += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                    // DEBUG
                    if (debug)
                        Log.e(TAG, "|__ Thread running since : " + timeElapsed + " ms");

                    if (timeElapsed >= durationInMilliseconds) {
                        stopFlag = true;
                        if (debug)
                            Log.e(TAG, "|__ Time elapsed - Process stopped");
                    }

                }




            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Catch : " + e.toString());
            }
        } /* end of "run" */

    }; /* end of Thread */

    t.start();

    // reset stopFlag for next Toast
    stopFlag = false;

} /* end showFor */
```

Answer (score 1):

Toast show and dismiss are done using a `handler`. So the thread which creates the toast should be running till the toast is dismissed, so that handler can process dismiss message. So create the Toast in UI thread.

Make sure `mySingleToast` is created in Ui thread

Edit: Since you are creating the toast in Ui thread, looks like, in your case too many atoast.show() are queued up. LENGTH_SHORT usually shows up for 2 seconds. And in that duration you have added almost 6-7 shows. That is why it continues to be shown.

What you could do is add `aToast.cancel()` just before `aToast.show` too.

Comment: I confirm that mySingleToast is created in onCreate.